# Событие, если отсутствует ссылка

Tags: javascript, html

Есть следующий html:

```
<ul id="Pagination">
    <li class="ImagePrev"><?php previous_post_link('<a>%link</a>')?></li>
    <li class="ImageNext"><?php next_post_link('<a>%link</a>')?></li>
</ul>
```

У каждого `li` есть свой `background` и, если отсутствует ссылка, нужно чтобы пропадал background!
Моя попытка:

```
if(("#Pagination a") == 0){
    alert("1");
  }
```

Comment: Вы наверное хотели написать `if($("#Pagination a").length == 0)` ?

Comment: Если имеется ввиду, что домен под ссылкой живой - это можно проверить через img тег наличие картинки на другом сайте (это не означает что страницу куда ссылается ccылка не могут удалить), используя onerror событие. А так с помощью JS можно проверить только синтаксиз ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селектор `:empty` выберет `li`, у которых нет содержимого. Это решает задачу?

**1) через [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp)**

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/854oopmp/

```css
/* heart of the matter */
.ImagePrev {
  background-color: green;
}
.ImagePrev:empty {
  background-color: grey;
}

/* nice look */
#Pagination {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
#Pagination li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
#Pagination li > a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="Pagination">
  <li class="ImagePrev"></li>
  <li class="ImagePrev"><a></a></li>
  <li class="ImagePrev"><a>link</a></li>
  <li class="ImagePrev"><a href="link">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**2) через [jQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)**

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/hmw21yyr/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ImagePrev:empty').css('background-color', 'grey');
});
```

```css
/* heart of the matter */
.ImagePrev {
  background-color: green;
}

/* nice look */
#Pagination {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
#Pagination li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
#Pagination li > a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="Pagination">
  <li class="ImagePrev"></li>
  <li class="ImagePrev"><a></a></li>
  <li class="ImagePrev"><a>link</a></li>
  <li class="ImagePrev"><a href="link">link</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ )

```
if($(".ImagePrev").children('a').length === 0){
    $(".ImagePrev").hide();
  }
```

Comment: первый комментарий от Алексея в вашем вопросе, более корректный, я бы сказал, вызывать лишний метод здесь ну уж совсем не нужно

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев вообще скорее ни мой ни этот ответ не являются до конца правильными....... на самом деле надо пробегаться по всем `.ImagePrev` и прятать лишь определенные блоки..... а так получится что скроются все...... и то в случае, если везде нет ссылок ........ а надо бы `$(".ImagePrev").each(function(){ if ($(this).find('a').length == 0) { $(this).hide(); }  });`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну да, тут надо фигурировать `this`, кстати попробуй писать не `$(this).find('a')`, а `$('a', this)`, структурно меньше методов вызывается

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, там же все равно внутри тот же самый `find`